# Exclude branches from condition tree, remove unused code

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a big class and I suppose that some parts of it are never used, but PMD, Findbugs can not show it as unused code part. The code looks like:

```
public void function1(....., String something) {

  BigDecimal myNumber=new BigDecimal(something);

.....

  String variable1 =  function2(something);

}


public void function1(String something) {
  if (something.charAt('R')>-1) {
    ..... UNUSED CODE ....
   }

}
```

If the something parameter contains and R alphabet, then the BigDecimal conversion will throw an exception. Is there any static code analyser or any other tool that could help to find such code parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you write a unit/system test to exercise these methods.  Once you have this you can get a code coverage report and see which lines are called and which branches are taken.